# Check if table variable Exists?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Ive searched StackOverFlow , and didnt find any.

Is there any way for me to know if a Table **Variable** already exists ?

something like :

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tbl
```

but for table **Var**...

Comment: Are you asking about table variables or temporary tables? These are _different_ things.

Comment: Is there ever a need to know this, given that table variables are scoped to the batch and fall out of scope once the batch completes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table variables, because they are *variables*, are distinct from either temporary or non-temporary tables in that they are not *created* – they are *declared*. They are much closer in that respect to ‘normal’ variables rather than to tables.

So, there's as much sense in talking about a table variable's existence as in talking about the existence of any variable: if you have declared the thing in your source code, it exists starting from that point until the end of its scope, which, in SQL Server, is known to be either the batch or the stored procedure/function it is declared in. And if you haven't declared the variable and are trying to reference it in your code, your code will just not compile, rendering any existence check pointless, if ever possible.

Perhaps, if you feel the need to drop and re-(create/declare) a table variable in your script, then you should probably consider using a temporary table instead.

Comment: before i drop a table I should check if it exists , otherwise - i wil get exception.......

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, of course, I wasn't arguing that. My point was, table variables are not fit for dropping/recreating/existence check, but temporary tables are. If you want to drop/recreate a temporary row set in your code, use a temporary table instead of a table variable.

Comment: +1 They are created implicitly whenever the scope containing a table variable declaration is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Table variables `@table` are little bit different from temporary tables `#table`.
Table variables `@table` need to declare while temporary tables `#table` should create.
So as per definition declare variables exist between their defined scope (`Begin` and `End`) statement. So no need to drop table variables.

But you can use `delete @table` statement if you want to delete/drop a table variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but hopefully this might help someone who lands here.  When developing from SSMS, you may want to re-run a statement that selects into a table variable (eg. `select * into #tblvarFoo from dbName.schema.Foo`). But, the second time you run it, you get an error that it already exists.  So, you decide to drop it first. But then, you have the problem the OP had:

> Before I drop a table I should check if it exists, otherwise I will
>   get an exception...

You don't have to drop the table variable or check for its existence.
Just reconnect (right click in the query window and select "Connection->Change Connection...") to same Server/db as before.